# Prove $\, a_1 \Bbb Z \cap \dotsb \cap a_r \mathbb{Z} = {\rm lcm}(a_1, \ldots, a_r) \Bbb Z\ $ [lcm = ideal intersection]

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Let be $$ a_1,\ldots,a_r \in \mathbb{N} $$

I want to show that

$$  a_1 \Bbb Z \cap \dotsb \cap a_r \mathbb{Z} = {\rm lcm}(a_1, \ldots, a_r) \Bbb Z$$

ok,I know that $ {2}\Bbb Z \cap 3\mathbb{Z} = 6\mathbb{Z}. $
I struggle getting an idea of how to prove it correctly, maybe you guys can help!

Comment: Maybe induction on $r$?

Comment: Like xbh says. Can you prove that $2\mathbb Z \cap 3\mathbb Z = 6\mathbb Z$? Try to generalise that proof to two arbitrary natural numbers. Then use induction on $r$.

Comment: I'm guessing $\mathbb Z_a = a\mathbb Z = \{ka \mid k\in\mathbb Z\}$?

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/663870/intersection-of-two-ideals-in-the-ring-of-integers

Comment: This is either very weird notation or just plain non-sense. Are you sure you didn't mean to discuss $a\Bbb{Z}$ instead of $\Bbb{Z}_a$? I suppose $\Bbb{Z}_2$ and $\Bbb{Z}_3$ could both be viewed as subsets of the power set of $\Bbb{Z}$. But in that case their intersection is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$c \in a_1\Bbb Z\cap\cdots\cap a_r\Bbb Z\iff a_1,\ldots,a_r\mid c\!\!\color{#c00}{\overset{\rm U\!}\iff} \overbrace{{\rm lcm}(a_1,\ldots,a_r)}^{\large \ell}\mid c\iff  c\in\ell\,\Bbb Z\quad $$

where  $\,\rm\color{#c00}U = $ [Universal Property of LCM](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2322544/242) (which is the *definition* of lcm in general domains).

**Remark** $ $ Above is simply the PID case of the universal property of (ideal) intersection, i.e.

$\qquad\ \  A_1 \cap \cdots \cap A_n \supseteq C\iff A_1\supseteq C,\ldots, A_n\supseteq C$.

As such, one often *defines* $\,{\rm lcm}(A_1,\ldots,A_n) := A_1 \cap \cdots \cap A_n,\ $ for ideals $\,A_i,$

and, $ $ [dually](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3984822/242), $ $ one $ $ *defines* $ \  \gcd(A_1,\ldots,A_n) := A_1 + \cdots + A_n$

since in a PID $\,A\supseteq C\iff (a)\supseteq (c)\iff a\mid c,\,$ i.e. [contains = divides](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1291435/242).

Generally we don't have $\,{\rm lcm}(A,B)\gcd(A,B) = AB\,$ for $\,A,B\neq 0,\,$ but this does hold true in a broad class of domain known as Prufer domains - which are non-Noetherian generalizations of Dedekind domains. Their ubiquity stems from a remarkable confluence of interesting characterizations. For example, they are those domains satisfy either the Chinese Remainder Theorem for ideals, or Gauss's Lemma for polynomial content ideals, or for ideals: $\, A\cap (B + C) = A\cap B + A\cap C\,\,  $  or "contains = divides" $\, A\supset B\ \Rightarrow\ A\mid B\,$ for fin. gen. $A\,$ etc. It has been estimated that there are close to $100$ such characterizations known. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/14122/242) is around $30$ interesting ones.

Answer (score 1):

The ring $\Bbb Z$ of integers is a principal ideal ring. Therefore, we may choose unique $b\in\Bbb N$ such that $$ b\Bbb Z = a_1\Bbb Z\cap a_2\Bbb Z\cap ... \cap a_r\Bbb Z$$ implying $b$ must be a common multiple of $a_1,a_2,...,a_r$ whose least common multiple we denote $b'$ so that $b'\;|\;b$ and $$b'\Bbb Z \subset (a_1\Bbb Z\cap a_2\Bbb Z\cap ... \cap a_r\Bbb Z) = b\Bbb Z$$ implying $b\;|\;b'$ and therefore $b=b'$.