# Proof: In a commutative monoid $M$ with cancellation laws, if $a,b\in M$ are relatively prime then $\gcd(a,b)=\mathcal{U}(M)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $M$ be a commutative monoid for which the cancellation laws hold. Given $a,b\in M$, show that if $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime then $\gcd(a,b)=\mathcal{U}(M)$, where $\mathcal{U}(M)$ is the group of units of the monoid $M$.

I find the analogous proof for integers and integral domains everywhere, but I need to prove this for monoids. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your definition of "relatively prime"?

Comment: For $a,b\in M$, $a$ is relatively prime to $b$ if for every $x\in M$ such that $a\mid bx$ then $a\mid x$. In the statement that I gave, $a$ is relatively prime to $b$ and $b$ to $a$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Hint** $\,\ c\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\, a\mid b(a/c)\,\Rightarrow\, a\mid a/c\,\Rightarrow\, c\mid 1$

**Remark** $ $ There are [various notions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/164589/242) of $\,a,b\,$ are "relatively prime / coprime" in rings, e.g. below excerpted from the linked post. You might find it instructive to investigate their relationships also.

[0] $\ \ \ x\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\, x\mid 1$

[a] $\ \ \ a\mid bx \,\Rightarrow\,   a\mid x $

[b] $\ \ \  a,b\mid x  \,\Rightarrow\,  ab\mid x $

[c] $\ \ \ (a)\cap (b) =  (ab)$

Comment: What does the notation $(a)\cap (b)=(ab)$ mean? sorry I'm sorta new to abstract algebra. Also, what did you mean when you wrote "[0], [a],[b], and [c]"?

Comment: @SimonFraser $\ (a)\,$  denotes the [ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory)) $aR$ in  a commutative ring $R$, i.e. all multiples of $a$,  The brackets are just labels (consistent with the linked post). S

Comment: @SimonFraser The definition of gcd doesn't vary but "relatively prime" may.

Comment: @Simon No, it is correct as written, see [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/663882/242)

Comment: @BillDubuqueI completely misunderstood. I was thinking of something completely illogical. You are correct.